# Ayuda SQL Server - Consultas con rangos de Fecha

Tags: sql-server, date, sql

**Pregunta Modificada**

tengo que realizar la siguiente consulta, **Sin usar Sub-Consultas**... "Muestre los clientes (identificación y nombre completo) de los clientes que compraron en los últimos 12 meses", ya he realizado el siguiente código en la consulta.

```
select Facturas.Identificacion, NombreCli +' '+ Apellido as 'Nombre Completo', FechaCompra as 'Fecha 
de Compra' 
from Clientes
inner join Facturas on Clientes.Identificacion=Facturas.Identificacion
where DATEDIFF(M,FechaCompra,SYSUTCDATETIME())< 12
```

Mas sin embargo esta consulta no me arroja resultados ya que la ultima venta se realizó hace mas de 1 año (30-01-2109 - Ver imagen), por ende al comparar con la fecha actual del sistema, no me arroja nada...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora yo pudiese utilizar `Datediff` pero me pide que le pase 3 criterios, en este caso si lo uso de esta manera.. Ver el siguiente código.

```
select Facturas.Identificacion, NombreCli +' '+ Apellido as 'Nombre Completo', FechaCompra as 'Fecha de Compra' 
from Clientes
inner join Facturas on Clientes.Identificacion=Facturas.Identificacion
where DATEDIFF(M,'2019-01-30','2018-06-01')< 12
```

Ahí tendría que tener conocimiento de cual es la fecha de compra inicial en la base de datos, y cual es la fecha de compra final. Suponiendo que no conozco estas fechas, no sabría cual es la ultima fecha de compra registrada para poder restarle 12 meses y que de tal manera, me arroje las compras realizadas en los últimos 12 meses.

Adjunto la estructura de la base de datos y las relaciones entre tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya les agradezco por sus respuestas...

Comment: Cuando dices "Quisiera que tome la última fecha registrada en la base de datos", te refieres a la máxima fecha de compra por cliente, máxima fecha en general que tiene guardada la DB o a la fecha actual del servidor (?).

Comment: Saludos @JosueArriola, me refiero a la máxima fecha de compra por el cliente. A partir de ello, descontar (Por así decirlo) 12 meses atrás, y que como resultado me traiga las ventas realizadas en esos 12 meses. No se,  si me hago comprender

Comment: Lo que estás diciendo en este comentario, no tiene nada que ver con tu pregunta. Dices: "Muestre los clientes (identificación y nombre completo) de los clientes que compraron en los últimos 12 meses", nada habla de las ventas. Por favor trata de clarificar todo, editando tu pregunta y agregando toda la información pertinente (un ejemplo de datos sería perfecto) y no lo hagas en lo comentarios. Aclara también que tienes que resolver todo sin usar subconsultas . Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu observación @PatricioMoracho la pregunta fue modificada teniendo en cuanta tus observaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Varias posibilidades. Pero primero varias anotaciones.

No parece correcto que, según la consulta que muestras Facturas.Identificación, sea el criterio de union con Clientes.Identificación. En mi ejemplo he generado un idCliente, ya que no has puesto la estructura de las tablas.

En el enunciado no se observa que se requiera la fecha de la compra, sólo los datos de clientes, por tanto la columna FechaCompra no parece que tenga que salir en la misma.

```
create table clientes
             (
             NombreCli      varchar(100)
           , Apellido       varchar(100)
           , identificacion int
             );

create table Facturas
             (
             Id          int identity(1, 1)
           , idCliente   int
           , fechaCompra date
             );
go

Insert into clientes(NombreCli
                   , Apellido
                   , identificacion)
values
       ( 'Ana', 'Servia', 1 ),
       ( 'Adolfo', 'Azul', 2 ),
       ( 'Silvia', 'Sanz', 3 );

Insert into Facturas(idCliente
                   , fechaCompra)
values
       ( 1, '20190130' ),
       ( 2, '20190128' ),
       ( 1, '20190125' ),
       ( 2, '20190121' ),
       ( 3, '20180120' ),
       ( 2, '20180120' ),
       ( 1, '20180120' );
go
-- opcion 1

with cte
     as (
     -- ultima fecha de compra
     select top (1) fechaCompra
            from facturas
     order by fechaCompra desc)
     Select d.identificacion
          , d.NombreCli
          , d.Apellido
            from clientes AS d
                      inner join Facturas AS f on d.identificacion = f.idCliente
                      cross join cte -- cruzamos todas las operaciones anteriores con la cte
            where f.fechaCompra > dateadd(month, -12, cte.fechaCompra) -- filtramos por los últimos 12 meses
            group by d.identificacion
                   , d.NombreCli
                   , d.Apellido;

-- opcion 2.     

-- utilizando una variable.
Declare @FECHAFAC date = dateadd(month, -12, ( (
                                                 select max(fechaCompra)
                                                        from facturas
                                               )
                                             ) );

select c.identificacion
     , c.NombreCli
     , c.Apellido
       from Facturas AS f
                 inner join clientes AS c on f.idCliente = c.identificacion
                 cross apply (-- obtener 
                               Select top (1) fechaCompra
                                      from Facturas
                                      where Facturas.idCliente = c.identificacion and Facturas.fechaCompra > @FECHAFAC
                                      order by fechaCompra desc
                             ) AS v
    group by c.identificacion, c.NombreCli, c.Apellido;
-- opcion 3

Declare @FECHAFAC2 date = dateadd(month, -12, ( (
                                                  select max(fechaCompra)
                                                         from facturas
                                                )
                                              ) );

Select distinct 
       c.identificacion
     , c.NombreCli
     , c.Apellido
       from clientes AS c
                 inner join Facturas AS f on f.idCliente = c.identificacion
       where f.fechaCompra > @FECHAFAC2;

-- opción 4 con una función escalar
Create function dbo.maxFechaCompra ()
returns date
as
begin
    return 
    (
        Select max(fechaCompra) as maxFecha from Facturas
    )
end 
go
Select distinct 
       c.identificacion
     , c.NombreCli
     , c.Apellido
       from clientes AS c
                 inner join Facturas AS f on f.idCliente = c.identificacion
     where 
        f.fechaCompra > dateadd(month,-12,dbo.maxFechaCompra()); --invocamos a la función
```

Todos los ejemplos están pensados para que si fuese necesario, puedas añadir la columna de fecha de compra directamente. A excepción de los dos primeros, donde sería necesario quitar la cláusula group by.

[Cte correlativo](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-2-correlativos/)

Comment: Hola @JaviFer2 gracias por tu respuesta, de antemano ofrezco disculpas por no subir la imagen de la estructura de las tablas y relaciones, (Soy nuevo en Stack overflow)...En tu ejercicio creado para explicarme veo que en los 3 casos se requiere usar Subconsulta, con esto creería, que quizás es poner los rangos de fecha manualmente como lo expuse, ya que en el requisito me piden no usar Subconsulta en la búsqueda.

Comment: Hola @JonathanArias. ¿Porqué dices que se utilizan subconsultas? ¿Qué es para ti una subconsulta?. En el ejemplo 1 se utiliza una tabla de expresión común. En la opción 2 se utiliza una variable, y el operador apply. En el ejemplo 3 una variable y la query contra la variable. En el ejemplo 4 se utiliza una función escalar. Realmente no comprendo lo que esperas. Utilizar subconsultas seria Select * from xxx where fecha > (select fecha from x)

Comment: [Subconsultas] (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=Una%20subconsulta%20es%20una%20consulta,statement%2C%20or%20inside%20another%20subquery.)

Comment: Saludos @JaviFer2 validando con mi instructor al parecer lo que pedía era algo no tan complejo, me dijo que podía solucionarlo con el `Datediff(M,fechaCompra,getDate())` al parecer me complique en la solución pensando variantes que de momento no era necesario.